# How would I be able to change the color of my nametag in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

So what I want to do is after the NameTag is cloned I want to be able to change the color of the nametag with a GUI button. I have tried this and for me at least it seems that It will be very difficult but if any you have answers tell me ;)

Comment: would you please read [ask]. your questions are of very poor quality. last time you did not even bother to answer my comment... you should share your attempt to solve this. you expect people to help you . the least you can do is invest ore than 30 seconds into your post. is there even a nametag in roblox? a quick websearch suggests that you have to implement this as it is not a standard object

Comment: It is a custom nametag using billboard GUI parented to the characters head

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide any useful infromaton I'll keep it short:

BillboardGui is a container for GUI objects. Nametags are usually implemented with TextLabels wich have a color property which can be changed.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BillboardGui

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TextLabel

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/TextLabel/TextColor3